# Linux Bash function conditional execution user input

Tags: linux, bash, function, conditional-statements

I am trying to read user input with such as yes and no and executing a function which works fine, but it exit the script after one execution.

When user input is yes or Y key, I want to script to execute the stated function and then repeat the previous step.

here is the script.

```
redosmartcheck () {
read -n1 -p "Do you want to Hot Swap the Hard Disks and reperform the smart test? [y,n]" doit
case $doit in
  y|Y) smartcheck;;
  n|N) echo "continuing to the next stage to wipe all hard disk drives" ;;
  *) echo dont know ;;
esac
}
redosmartcheck
exit 0
```

If user press Y key, the script executes smartcheck function and exit the script. How I can make it repeat redosmartcheck function rather than exit?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to insert a `while`:

```
redosmartcheck () {
  while [[ $doit == "" || $doit =~ y|Y ]]; do
    read -n1 -p "Do you want to Hot Swap the Hard Disks and reperform the smart test? [y,n]" doit
    case $doit in
      y|Y) smartcheck;;
      n|N) echo "continuing to the next stage to wipe all hard disk drives" ;;
      *) echo "dont know";;
    esac
  done
}

redosmartcheck
```